# Non deterministic behavior of native_ functions in OpenCL kernel

Tags: gpu, opencl, opencl-c

**TL;DR:** Using native_log2() produces non deterministic behavior in OpenCL kernel, while using log2() produces deterministic behavior. Why is this happening?

So I have this function below acting as a helper function for an OpenCL kernel, and I was using the native_ version of log2 (**native_log2**) to improve speed performance.

When I was comparing the results produced by the kernel and by the original program, I realized that in most of the cases the kernel is producing the right values, however, sometimes it produces an incorrect value (**like 30 incorrect values in 500k function calls**). **VERY IMPORTANT:** The errors are not always on the same computations. I am processing multiple input files, and the errors seem to occur randomly in different sets of files with different runs. That is, the results are non deterministic.

After some tests I narrowed the problem to the function below and found out that **swapping the native_log2 by log2 produces the correct value 100% of the times**. All those typecasts look ugly, but the log2() and floor() functions are only compatible with double/float, while my input/output must be integers.

My device is a NVIDIA GPU 940MX and only supports OpenCL 1.2. [The OpenCL 1.2 documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf) states that

> A subset of functions from table 6.8 that are defined with the native_ prefix. These functions may map to one or more native device instructions and will typically have better performance compared to the corresponding functions (without the native__ prefix) described in table 6.8. The accuracy (and in some cases the input range(s)) of these functions is implementation-defined.

Clearly I am supposed to expect some errors when using native_ functions, but the documentation is not clear about the determinism of the errors I may be encountering.

Can someone give me directions on why I am facing this strange behavior?

```
int xGetExpGolombNumberOfBits(int value){
    unsigned int uiLength2 = 1;
    unsigned int uiTemp2 = select((unsigned int)( value << 1 ), ( (unsigned int)( -value ) << 1 ) + 1, value <= 0);
    
    // These magic numbers (7 and 128) are substituting two constants for the sake of clarity
    while( uiTemp2 > 128 ) 
    {
      uiLength2 += ( 7 << 1 );
      uiTemp2  >>=   7;
    }

    return uiLength2 + (((int)floor(native_log2((float)uiTemp2))) << 1);
}
```

Comment: Not quite answering your question, but perhaps you can avoid all the log2 problems by using [`clz`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clz.html)?

Comment: I actually got rid of the problem by avoiding the native_log2() and using the standard log2() function. The core of my question (which maybe was not clear enough) is WHY this is happening so I can avoid facing similar problems with native_ functions in the future.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer :) But checking the `clz` solution might help pinpointing the problem. Specifically, whether there is something wrong with `native_log2` itself, or is the problem elsewhere, and `native_log2` just triggers it. For example, there might be a data race outside of this function, and `log2` is slow enough to prevent it.